# MVC form action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a edit View - Product/Edit/1
1 being the Id of the Product.How can I set the action of the edit post in the View to the POST edit action

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
     public ActionResult Edit(int Id, FormCollection collection)
```

The form tag is prepopulated as 
but I want to set it to /Product/Edit/1

I am using this

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm()){ %>
```

but know its not right.Can someone help me how to set the form action using the htmlhelper class extension method to the Url in the browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the intellisense for creating a Form with the HtmlHelper you will see there are parameters for specifying routeValues (of type object). Here you can specify the ID.

Your Edit View will be strongly typed with your Product object so you can specify Model.ID.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Product", new { Id = Model.ID } %>
...
```